# 'Error: ORA-01722: invalid number' when inserting into a table?

Tags: oracle

I'm very new to SQL and I am having trouble with an assignment that involves inserting records into a table. So far I have:

```
insert into show (show_id,production_company_id, 
genre,name_of_show,mpaa_rating,feature_type) values
(1,1,'comedy','click','r','movie');
```

It keeps telling me the specified number is invalid and to specify a number but I don't know what that means since there is already a number there. I tried looking at other similar questions on the site, but most of them were a lot more complicated than what I have here. Thanks for any help.

edit: also, production_company_id is a foreign key if that helps at all.

here is the original table:

```
CREATE TABLE show (
SHOW_ID number(6,0) PRIMARY KEY,
PRODUCTION_COMPANY_ID NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL REFERENCES PRODUCTION_COMPANY (PRODUCTION_COMPANY_ID),
GENRE VARCHAR(25),
NAME_OF_SHOW VARCHAR(25),
MPAA_RATING VARCHAR(25),
FEATURE_TYPE VARCHAR(25)

);
```

Comment: What does your table look like?

Comment: Show the table definition. What are the column data types?

Comment: Which SQL platform are you using?  I'm guessing Oracle based on the error, but not all RDBMS are the same.

Comment: Can you please put your table design as well?

Comment: It is probably happening because the one of the columns `genre`, `name_of_show`, `mpaa_rating`, or `feature_type` has been declared in the database schema as numeric.  If that doesn't explain it, you need to provide an MCVE.

Comment: Are we sure that there is a record in production_company table having Id = 1 ?

Comment: Could you please check if PRODUCTION_COMPANY_ID is defined as "number" in the table PRODUCTION_COMPANY ?

Comment: just checked the table and it appears PRODUCTION_COMPANY_ID is varchar2

Comment: I don't understand. If the `CREATE TABLE` was indeed what you show in your post, then how did that column change from `NUMBER` to `VARCHAR2`? What are we to believe? Keep in mind that credibility is a valuable attribute, don't lose it!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that `PRODUCTION_COMPANY_ID` is defined as `number` in the table `PRODUCTION_COMPANY`, because in your table creation of `show`, `production_company_id` refers to that table.

If not, you can modify the column type like:

```
ALTER TABLE PRODUCTION_COMPANY
MODIFY PRODUCTION_COMPANY_ID number;
```

Or if you do not want to change the type of that column for some reason, you can try:

```
insert into show (show_id,production_company_id, 
genre,name_of_show,mpaa_rating,feature_type) values
(1,'1','comedy','click','r','movie');
```

Comment: You are welcome! I appreciate if you select the answer as the correct answer by clicking the tick on the left. Regards. @ForryB